# Assign variable from text

Tags: c#

I am trying to read some text from a text file and assign each line to a different variable.

I believe I do understand why my program outputs the wrong data, but I am not sure how to approach it differently.

Hoping someone may point me in he right direction or offer advice for me to take a different approach.

```
namespace Towns{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Town York = new Town();

        //York.Name = "York";
        //York.Population = 1345;

        printTownDetails(York, "York.txt");

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    private static void printTownDetails(Town _town, string txtFile)
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(txtFile);

        string line = "";

        while (line != null)
        {
            line = reader.ReadLine();

            if (line != null)
            {
                _town.Name = line;
                /*From my novice debugging skills I think this
                is why my program outputs only the second line in the text file.
                 The loop overwrites the _town.Name variable with the second line.*/
                _town.Population = line;
            }

        }
            Console.WriteLine("Town: {0}", _town.FormatMe());
    }
}
class Town
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Population { get; set; }

    public string FormatMe()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} - {1}",
            this.Name,
            this.Population);
    }
}}
```

The text file contains only two variables.

```
York
1345
```

Comment: Read about arrays/lists.....

Comment: When you run that code ? what is the output  of this `Console.WriteLine("Town: {0}", _town.FormatMe());`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can do this below.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) But instead of writing to the console just load the information to your variables.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test 
{

    public static void Main() 
    {
        string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
        try 
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path)) 
            {
                while (sr.Peek() >= 0) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());

                }
            }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the block of code that reads if(line!=null) you can have an index running and increment it each time you read a line of code. Then all of your strings will be stored in an array, and you can set them equal to variables from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this if you always have only two lines in the file:

```
private static void printTownDetails(Town _town, string txtFile)
{   
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(txtFile);
    _town.Name = lines[0];
    _town.Population = lines[1];

    Console.WriteLine("Town: {0}", _town.FormatMe());
}
```